# Javascript & PHP : how to apply javascript variable inside php tag

Tags: javascript, php

```
function retrieveHasilRawatJalan(row, kd_klp) {
   var hasil_rawat_jalan2 = <?php echo
   Modules::run("lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code","HL-024") ?>; 
}
```

> how to replace "HL-024" with variable kd_klp?

i get an error if i use it this way

```
 function retrieveHasilRawatJalan(row, kd_klp) {
       var hasil_rawat_jalan2 = <?php echo
       Modules::run("lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code",?>kd_klp<?php) ?>; 
 }
```

the error say Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>'

if my question isnt clear, please ask Thanks^^

**UPDATE**

**Before add AJAX**

```js
 /**
  *
  * @param {type} id
  * @returns {undefined}
  */
 function retrieveHasilRawatJalan(row) {
   var hasil_rawat_jalan2 = <? php echo Modules::run("lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code", "HL-003") ?> ;

   //var hasil_rawat_jalan2 = <?php //echo Modules::run("lab/get_row_content_from_lab_code", row)                                     ?>;
   var number_of_row = parseInt(Object.size(hasil_rawat_jalan2));
   var row_start = parseInt(row);

   addNewRow(number_of_row);
   var row_end = (number_of_row + row_start);

   j = 1;
   for (i = row_start; i <= row_end; i++) {
     document.getElementById('SUBKLP[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['sub_klp'];
     document.getElementById('NAMA[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['name_of_inspection'];
     document.getElementById('KODE[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['inspection_id'];
     document.getElementById('HASIL[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['result'];
     //document.getElementById('NILAI_NORMAL[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['normal_result'];
     document.getElementById('NILAI_NORMAL[' + i + ']').value = 'null';
     document.getElementById('SATUAN[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['measure_unit'];
     document.getElementById('KDKLP[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['klp_id'];
     j++;
   }
   console.log("row start: " + row_start + ", row end:" + row_end + ", column length: " + number_of_row);
 }
```

**After Add AJAX**

```js
/**
     * test ajax
     * @param {type} row
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    function retrieveHasilRawatJalan2() {

      var row = "HL-003";
      var hasil_rawat_jalan2;

      var xhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText; //to print on <p id="demo"></p>
          hasil_rawat_jalan2 = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      
      //this isnt work
      xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("
        lab / get_row_content_from_lab_code / ") ?>" + row, true);
      
      //this work
      xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("
        lab / get_row_content_from_lab_code /HL-003") ?>", true);

      xhttp.send();

      var number_of_row = parseInt(Object.size(JSON.parse(hasil_rawat_jalan2))); //try to change hasil_rawat_jalan2 to json but fail.
      var row_start = parseInt(row);

      addNewRow(number_of_row);
      var row_end = (number_of_row + row_start);

      j = 1;
      for (i = row_start; i <= row_end; i++) {
        document.getElementById('SUBKLP[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['sub_klp'];
        document.getElementById('NAMA[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['name_of_inspection'];
        document.getElementById('KODE[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['inspection_id'];
        document.getElementById('HASIL[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['result'];
        //document.getElementById('NILAI_NORMAL[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['normal_result'];
        document.getElementById('NILAI_NORMAL[' + i + ']').value = 'null';
        document.getElementById('SATUAN[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['measure_unit'];
        document.getElementById('KDKLP[' + i + ']').value = hasil_rawat_jalan2[j]['klp_id'];
        j++;
      }
      console.log("row start: " + row_start + ", row end:" + row_end + ", column length: " + number_of_row);
    }
```

problems after update ajax,

1. I assign `var row = "HL-003";` but i wasnt able to assign variable row to `xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("
           lab / get_row_content_from_lab_code / ") ?>" + row, true);` unless i write it directly like this `xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo site_url("
           lab / get_row_content_from_lab_code /HL-003") ?>", true);`
2. I get result from `xhttp.open("POST", "<?php echo
   site_url("
           lab / get_row_content_from_lab_code /HL-003") ?>", true);` but it return string not object eventhough format of the string is the same. so i change `hasil_rawat_jalan2 = xhttp.responseText;` and add   `JSON.parse(hasil_rawat_jalan2); //try to change hasil_rawat_jalan2 to object but fail.`

Comment: Does that file run through the php parser? If it's just plain js delivered to the client the php code won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Its impossible to place a `javascript` value (clientside) in `PHP` (serverside).
Unless you use AJAX to get the page and send the variable along as a POST/GET value.

`javascript` values get stored in your browser **after** the page has been loaded. And `PHP` executes **before** the page is sent to the browser. Therefor this is impossible in the way you want it in your question. (For as far as i understand the question :p)

[Example for ajax request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp)

Comment: While that is true, I believe that OP have simply mixed the two things around, as it looks (at least to me) like he is trying to put a php variable inside a js function.

Comment: @Thaillie, thanks for your info. could you please provide an example using ajax?, then i'll mark your answer

Comment: @stacheldraht27 Added a link to a site with useful information/examples.

Comment: could you provide the code?

Comment: @stacheldraht27 click the link at the bottom of the answer, there are quite some examples and explanation there.

Comment: @Thaillie , updated what i got so far